# Gnuplot doesnt plot data for y above 100

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot particle density, my file has 3 columns, x, y and density, looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV8tx.png) . If i have a 100x100 lattice, I can plot  without a problem. Anything above 100 in y range won't plot tho.
Example: I wanted to plot a 300x300 lattice, but it only plots y below 100:

[image: example]

Does anyone know what could be the cause for this? I checked the file and there are no faulty values, everything seems to be correct there.

This is my gnuplot code:

```
set size ratio 1
set xrange [0:300]
set yrange [0:300]
set palette positive nops_allcF maxcolors 0 gamma 1.5 color model CMY
plot 'profil0871' with image

  0.000000  0.000000  0.999822
  1.000000  0.000000  0.999763
  2.000000  0.000000  0.999737
  3.000000  0.000000  0.999725
  4.000000  0.000000  0.999720
  5.000000  0.000000  0.999719
  6.000000  0.000000  0.999720
  7.000000  0.000000  0.999722
  8.000000  0.000000  0.999725
  9.000000  0.000000  0.999728
 10.000000  0.000000  0.999731
 11.000000  0.000000  0.999735
 12.000000  0.000000  0.999739
 13.000000  0.000000  0.999743
 14.000000  0.000000  0.999747
 15.000000  0.000000  0.999751
 16.000000  0.000000  0.999755
 17.000000  0.000000  0.999760
 18.000000  0.000000  0.999764
 19.000000  0.000000  0.999768
 20.000000  0.000000  0.999772
 21.000000  0.000000  0.999777
 22.000000  0.000000  0.999781
 23.000000  0.000000  0.999786
 24.000000  0.000000  0.999790
 25.000000  0.000000  0.999794
 26.000000  0.000000  0.999799
 27.000000  0.000000  0.999803
 28.000000  0.000000  0.999808
 29.000000  0.000000  0.999812
 30.000000  0.000000  0.999816
 31.000000  0.000000  0.999821
 32.000000  0.000000  0.999825
 33.000000  0.000000  0.999830
 34.000000  0.000000  0.999835
 35.000000  0.000000  0.999839
 36.000000  0.000000  0.999844
 37.000000  0.000000  0.999848
 38.000000  0.000000  0.999853
 39.000000  0.000000  0.999857
 40.000000  0.000000  0.999862
 41.000000  0.000000  0.999867
 42.000000  0.000000  0.999872
 43.000000  0.000000  0.999876
 44.000000  0.000000  0.999881
 45.000000  0.000000  0.999886
 46.000000  0.000000  0.999891
 47.000000  0.000000  0.999895
 48.000000  0.000000  0.999900
 49.000000  0.000000  0.999905
 50.000000  0.000000  0.999910
 51.000000  0.000000  0.999915
 52.000000  0.000000  0.999920
 53.000000  0.000000  0.999925
 54.000000  0.000000  0.999930
 55.000000  0.000000  0.999935
 56.000000  0.000000  0.999940
 57.000000  0.000000  0.999945
 58.000000  0.000000  0.999950
 59.000000  0.000000  0.999955
 60.000000  0.000000  0.999960
 61.000000  0.000000  0.999965
 62.000000  0.000000  0.999971
 63.000000  0.000000  0.999976
 64.000000  0.000000  0.999981
 65.000000  0.000000  0.999986
 66.000000  0.000000  0.999992
 67.000000  0.000000  0.999997
 68.000000  0.000000  1.000002
 69.000000  0.000000  1.000008
 70.000000  0.000000  1.000013
 71.000000  0.000000  1.000018
 72.000000  0.000000  1.000024
 73.000000  0.000000  1.000029
 74.000000  0.000000  1.000035
 75.000000  0.000000  1.000041
 76.000000  0.000000  1.000046
 77.000000  0.000000  1.000052
 78.000000  0.000000  1.000057
 79.000000  0.000000  1.000063
 80.000000  0.000000  1.000069
 81.000000  0.000000  1.000074
 82.000000  0.000000  1.000080
 83.000000  0.000000  1.000086
 84.000000  0.000000  1.000092
 85.000000  0.000000  1.000098
 86.000000  0.000000  1.000103
 87.000000  0.000000  1.000109
 88.000000  0.000000  1.000115
 89.000000  0.000000  1.000121
 90.000000  0.000000  1.000127
 91.000000  0.000000  1.000133
 92.000000  0.000000  1.000139
 93.000000  0.000000  1.000145
 94.000000  0.000000  1.000151
 95.000000  0.000000  1.000157
 96.000000  0.000000  1.000164
 97.000000  0.000000  1.000170
 98.000000  0.000000  1.000176
 99.000000  0.000000  1.000182
100.000000  0.000000  1.000188
101.000000  0.000000  1.000195
102.000000  0.000000  1.000201
103.000000  0.000000  1.000207
104.000000  0.000000  1.000214
105.000000  0.000000  1.000220
106.000000  0.000000  1.000226
107.000000  0.000000  1.000233
108.000000  0.000000  1.000239
109.000000  0.000000  1.000246
110.000000  0.000000  1.000252
111.000000  0.000000  1.000259
112.000000  0.000000  1.000265
113.000000  0.000000  1.000272
114.000000  0.000000  1.000279
115.000000  0.000000  1.000285
116.000000  0.000000  1.000292
117.000000  0.000000  1.000299
118.000000  0.000000  1.000305
119.000000  0.000000  1.000312
120.000000  0.000000  1.000319
121.000000  0.000000  1.000326
122.000000  0.000000  1.000333
123.000000  0.000000  1.000340
124.000000  0.000000  1.000346
125.000000  0.000000  1.000353
126.000000  0.000000  1.000360
127.000000  0.000000  1.000367
128.000000  0.000000  1.000374
129.000000  0.000000  1.000381
130.000000  0.000000  1.000388
131.000000  0.000000  1.000395
132.000000  0.000000  1.000403
133.000000  0.000000  1.000410
134.000000  0.000000  1.000417
135.000000  0.000000  1.000424
136.000000  0.000000  1.000431
137.000000  0.000000  1.000438
138.000000  0.000000  1.000446
139.000000  0.000000  1.000453
140.000000  0.000000  1.000460
141.000000  0.000000  1.000467
142.000000  0.000000  1.000475
143.000000  0.000000  1.000482
144.000000  0.000000  1.000489
145.000000  0.000000  1.000497
146.000000  0.000000  1.000504
147.000000  0.000000  1.000512
148.000000  0.000000  1.000519
149.000000  0.000000  1.000527
150.000000  0.000000  1.000534
151.000000  0.000000  1.000541
152.000000  0.000000  1.000549
153.000000  0.000000  1.000556
154.000000  0.000000  1.000564
155.000000  0.000000  1.000572
156.000000  0.000000  1.000579
157.000000  0.000000  1.000587
158.000000  0.000000  1.000594
159.000000  0.000000  1.000602
160.000000  0.000000  1.000610
161.000000  0.000000  1.000617
162.000000  0.000000  1.000625
163.000000  0.000000  1.000632
164.000000  0.000000  1.000640
165.000000  0.000000  1.000648
166.000000  0.000000  1.000655
167.000000  0.000000  1.000663
168.000000  0.000000  1.000671
169.000000  0.000000  1.000679
170.000000  0.000000  1.000686
171.000000  0.000000  1.000694
172.000000  0.000000  1.000702
173.000000  0.000000  1.000709
174.000000  0.000000  1.000717
175.000000  0.000000  1.000725
176.000000  0.000000  1.000732
177.000000  0.000000  1.000740
178.000000  0.000000  1.000748
179.000000  0.000000  1.000756
180.000000  0.000000  1.000763
181.000000  0.000000  1.000771
182.000000  0.000000  1.000779
183.000000  0.000000  1.000786
184.000000  0.000000  1.000794
185.000000  0.000000  1.000802
186.000000  0.000000  1.000809
187.000000  0.000000  1.000817
188.000000  0.000000  1.000825
189.000000  0.000000  1.000832
190.000000  0.000000  1.000840
191.000000  0.000000  1.000847
192.000000  0.000000  1.000855
193.000000  0.000000  1.000863
194.000000  0.000000  1.000870
195.000000  0.000000  1.000878
196.000000  0.000000  1.000885
197.000000  0.000000  1.000893
198.000000  0.000000  1.000900
199.000000  0.000000  1.000908
200.000000  0.000000  1.000915
201.000000  0.000000  1.000922
202.000000  0.000000  1.000930
203.000000  0.000000  1.000937
204.000000  0.000000  1.000944
205.000000  0.000000  1.000952
206.000000  0.000000  1.000959
207.000000  0.000000  1.000966
208.000000  0.000000  1.000973
209.000000  0.000000  1.000981
210.000000  0.000000  1.000988
211.000000  0.000000  1.000995
212.000000  0.000000  1.001002
213.000000  0.000000  1.001009
214.000000  0.000000  1.001016
215.000000  0.000000  1.001023
216.000000  0.000000  1.001030
217.000000  0.000000  1.001037
218.000000  0.000000  1.001044
219.000000  0.000000  1.001050
220.000000  0.000000  1.001057
221.000000  0.000000  1.001064
222.000000  0.000000  1.001071
223.000000  0.000000  1.001077
224.000000  0.000000  1.001084
225.000000  0.000000  1.001091
226.000000  0.000000  1.001097
227.000000  0.000000  1.001104
228.000000  0.000000  1.001110
229.000000  0.000000  1.001116
230.000000  0.000000  1.001123
231.000000  0.000000  1.001129
232.000000  0.000000  1.001135
233.000000  0.000000  1.001141
234.000000  0.000000  1.001148
235.000000  0.000000  1.001154
236.000000  0.000000  1.001160
237.000000  0.000000  1.001166
238.000000  0.000000  1.001172
239.000000  0.000000  1.001178
240.000000  0.000000  1.001184
241.000000  0.000000  1.001190
242.000000  0.000000  1.001195
243.000000  0.000000  1.001201
244.000000  0.000000  1.001207
245.000000  0.000000  1.001212
246.000000  0.000000  1.001218
247.000000  0.000000  1.001224
248.000000  0.000000  1.001229
249.000000  0.000000  1.001235
250.000000  0.000000  1.001240
251.000000  0.000000  1.001245
252.000000  0.000000  1.001251
253.000000  0.000000  1.001256
254.000000  0.000000  1.001261
255.000000  0.000000  1.001267
256.000000  0.000000  1.001272
257.000000  0.000000  1.001277
258.000000  0.000000  1.001282
259.000000  0.000000  1.001287
260.000000  0.000000  1.001292
261.000000  0.000000  1.001297
262.000000  0.000000  1.001302
263.000000  0.000000  1.001307
264.000000  0.000000  1.001312
265.000000  0.000000  1.001317
266.000000  0.000000  1.001322
267.000000  0.000000  1.001326
268.000000  0.000000  1.001331
269.000000  0.000000  1.001336
270.000000  0.000000  1.001341
271.000000  0.000000  1.001345
272.000000  0.000000  1.001350
273.000000  0.000000  1.001354
274.000000  0.000000  1.001359
275.000000  0.000000  1.001364
276.000000  0.000000  1.001368
277.000000  0.000000  1.001373
278.000000  0.000000  1.001377
279.000000  0.000000  1.001382
280.000000  0.000000  1.001386
281.000000  0.000000  1.001390
282.000000  0.000000  1.001395
283.000000  0.000000  1.001399
284.000000  0.000000  1.001403
285.000000  0.000000  1.001408
286.000000  0.000000  1.001412
287.000000  0.000000  1.001416
288.000000  0.000000  1.001420
289.000000  0.000000  1.001424
290.000000  0.000000  1.001428
291.000000  0.000000  1.001431
292.000000  0.000000  1.001435
293.000000  0.000000  1.001437
294.000000  0.000000  1.001439
295.000000  0.000000  1.001440
296.000000  0.000000  1.001439
297.000000  0.000000  1.001434
298.000000  0.000000  1.001423
299.000000  0.000000  1.001396
300.000000  0.000000  1.001338
  0.000000  1.000000  0.999770
  1.000000  1.000000  0.999743
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's difficult to tell if you don't show your gnuplot code. Please show your code and show data as text not as image.

Comment: @theozh Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I've added my gnuplot code to the post. How can I upload the whole data file?

Comment: Not sure what the limit of file/text size is on StackOverflow. Try to paste it as text and format it as code. How many different x-values and y-values do you have in your data? What is the range of your x- and y-values?

Comment: I posted first 303 lines of data, there are 90602 lines total. it's a 300x300 lattice, both x and y go from 0 to 300 and there is a density value for each x and y pair. the way it writes data in the file is start with y = 0 and write every x pair from 0 to 300, then y=1 and again every x from 0 to 300 and so on...

Comment: Could you please post some data lines with y-values larger than 100. They might be invalid for some reason. A wild guess: Is there still a space between x- and y-values?

Comment: Oh wow @maij this has to be it! As soon as y is greater than 99 there is no space between the values! I'll test it ASAP

Comment: oh wow I can't believe it, a mistake so simple and I didn't think of it. There was no space between the values, that's why it has been messing up. Thank you both so much for your effort, everything works as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

With the following minimal code I "mimic" your data and get the following.
Maybe you can try this code and tell what results you get. If you don't get a similar result then there seems to be something wrong with your code (try a `reset session` at the beginning) or something is still special with your data.

**Code:**

```
### plot with image
reset session

# create some random test data (will take some time for 90601 points)
set print $Data
    do for [y=0:300] for [x=0:300] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g", x, y, rand(0))
    }
set print

set size square

plot $Data with image
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Tried your code and the data is properly displayed among all y values.

Comment: @Andry Hmm, ok, but then there might be something "wrong" with your data. I've seen here that people were using pastebin.com to share data.